# How to map firestore data to typescript interface in Ionic / Angular app?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

Below are a couple of documents I am retrieving from firestore:

[image]

Here is the method I'm using:

```
private _mechanics = new BehaviorSubject<User[]>([]);

fetchMechanics() {

    return of(
      firebase.firestore().collection("users").where("isMechanic", "==", false)
        .get()
        .then((docs) => {
          const data = []
          docs.forEach((doc) => {
            data.push(doc);
          });
          console.log('Service Data:', data);
          this._mechanics.next(data)
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        })
    );

  }
```

Now I want to convert the data to follow my `UserData` interface:

```
interface UserData {
  userId: string,
  userName: string,
  isMechanic: boolean,
  location: PlaceLocation
}
```

Can someone please tell me what changes I need to make to `fetchMechanics()` to do this?

Here's an example of the data in firestore:

[image]

Also, I've been trying to copy the below code, but it hasn't worked so far:

```
private _users = new BehaviorSubject<User[]>([]);

fetchUsers() {
    return this.http
      .get<{ [key: string]: UserData }>('firebaseUrl/users.json')
      .pipe(map(resData => {
        const users = [];
        for (const key in resData) {
          if (resData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            users.push(
              new User(
                key,
                resData[key].userName,
                resData[key].isMechanic,
                resData[key].location)
            );
          }
        }
        return users;
      }),
        tap(users => {
          this._users.next(users);
        })
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if data in collection have same structure as interface you can just cast object  to interface as follow

```
interface UserData {
  userId: string,
  userName: string,
  isMechanic: boolean,
  location: PlaceLocation
}

private _mechanics = new BehaviorSubject<UserData[]>([]);

constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) {
}

fetchMechanics() {

  return this.firestore
    .collection("users")
    .ref
    .where("isMechanic", "==", false)
    .get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        const data: UserData[] = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            data.push(doc.data() as UserData);
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
        this._mechanics.next(data)
    });

}
```

Comment: I would like to suggest the following library :
https://github.com/angular/angularfire

Answer (score 0):

this is how I did it

getloc(){

```
 const db = this.fire.firestore;
 db.collection("buses").get().then((data)=>{
   console.log(data.docs.map(bus=>bus.data()));
 });
```

}